# Populating ref to the parent using Mongoose and displaying complete parent after authentication with passportjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose-plugins, passport.js

I have the following schema for `user` and `sp`. `sp` is short for service provider. Service provider is a user, it has a reference to user.
I am trying to signup and  singin using PassportJS module of NodeJS. I have been able to signup an `sp` and I could see the data persisted in MongoDB collections in  `users` and `sps` collections, but I am not able to display the complete data of sp on the profile page. I get to display only its user data. For example, I don't see the `sp`'s `spname` data in the profile page after authentication.

Following is some of the code:

**Schema for user:**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        ip: String,
        local            : {
            email        : String,
            password     : String
        }
        name: String ,
        created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    })
    .plugin(mongooseRole, {
        roles: ['public', 'user', 'sp', 'admin'],
        accessLevels: {
            'public': ['public', 'user', 'sp', 'admin'],
            'anon': ['public'],
            'user': ['user', 'admin'],
            'sp': ['sp', 'admin'],
            'admin': ['admin']
    }
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**Schema for sp:**

```
var spSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    spname: String,
});
var SP = mongoose.model("SP", spSchema);
```

**PassportJS code for logging in:**

```
//serialization/deserialization code
    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });


//authentication code
    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {

            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

                if(user.role == 'sp') {
                    SP.findOne({ user: user._id }).populate('user').exec(function(err, sp) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        if (!sp.user)
                            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No sp user found.')); 

                        if (!sp.user.validPassword(password))
                            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 
                        return done(null, sp);
                    });
                } 

                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 

                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 

                return done(null, user);
            });

        }));
```

**Displaying the profile:**

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

**profile.ejs**

```
<%= user %>
```

Could somebody help me with what should I be doing to display the whole `sp` object with all its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only querying `User` schema while deserializing. You need to deserialize `sp` if you want it. I'm not entirely sure about your situation but it seems that you're either authenticating a `User` ***or*** an `SP`, in which case you should similarly either deserializing `User` ***or*** `SP` (if `User` returns empty). Something like this maybe:

```
// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (user.role == 'sp')
            SP.findOne({user: user_id}).populate('user').exec(function(err, sp) {
                done(err, sp);
            });
        else done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply reflex. I am authenticating against only one collection `users`, only the additional data for `sp` is in the `sps` collections. Please tell me if authentication could be done using multiple table. Once I have a user authenticated, I check whether the given user is a normal user with `user` role, or if its an service provider with role `sp`. In the code answered by you for `deserializeUser`, would the code even run after `if(!err && user) return done(err, user);` if there is no error and the `user` is found? Would the `SP` data not lost if the user is found?

Comment: I had tried the following code, but it did not work either: `passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {         if(user.role = 'sp') {
                SP.findOne({user: user_id}).populate('user').exec(function (err, sp) {
                    if (!err) {
                         done(err, sp);
                    }
                }
            }
            done(err, user);
        });
});` What mistake am I committing here?

Comment: @laggingreflexes: I tried exactly that, but it did not work. There is a typo in your answer, just like I had it in my comment, it should be `==` in `if (user.role == 'sp')`. Thanks for the reply. I am not sure why am I still  getting just the data for the user schema even when it says that its a user with role `sp`?

Comment: @skip On second looks it should be `user.roles`. Be sure by logging `console.log(user.roles)`?

Comment: No reflex, `var newUser = newUser({email: 'email@email.com', role: 'user'});` this is an example of how you give a new user a `role`. You could check that at https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-role. And also I've got the data persisted for both `user` and `sp` correctly as I could see it with user having a `role` key. So `user.role` is fine.

Comment: @skip Are you still able to `console.log(user.role)`?

Comment: Yes reflex, the `user.role` is being compared as well for `if(user.role == 'sp')` and at many other places in the app.

Comment: @skip Can you `console.log(sp)` from the `SP.findOne(...,function(err, sp){...` callback?

Comment: @legginreflex: `console.log(sp)` displays the whole `sp` on the console, populated with `user` (`sp.user`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63268/discussion-between-laggingreflex-and-skip).